# Add different view in every row of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a ListView with custom row layout. Basically right now they show two labels, but now I need to add a dynamically customView of ImageView + label in every single row. For example, I can have a row with 2 labels, a row with  2 labels + n*(ImageView + anotherLabel). How can I manage that?

Comment: `customView of ImageView + label` ... **OMG**!! why don't you simply use a TextView with a compound drawable inside? 1 standard control, no naive custom controls...

Comment: ok, but I can have 0,1,n of this in every single row, how can I add them dynamically?

Comment: I think the closest thing to what you want to do is an `ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `BaseAdapter` and implement `getView` which should return/reuse the correct `View` type.
A really good tutorial to get started with `BaseAdapter` can be found at http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: I'm already doing this, but I can have 0, 1, n ImageView + Label to add, so I can add them to the xml layout, i need to add them dynamically.